# Jfrog artifactory search api ( pattern based) not working for few artifacts after migration

Tags: artifactory

We recently migrated our jfrog repo from inbuilt derby DB to mysql ( AWS RDS).

Artifactory version : 4.6.0 with pro pack.

Way we did was like this at a very high level:

1. Copy the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore folder to the new server's filestore folder
2. on old server , Perform full system export with the "Exclude Content" option selected (no other options selected)
3. On new server: Perform full system import (Do NOT select the Exclude Content option).

Everything else works fine .. but one issue we notice now is that for some artifacts search api using "pattern" is not working anymore. it works for other artifacts in the same repo but not for some specific ones.

Same search if done though AQL is working fine for all the artifacts.

So if i use "api/search/aql" api end point it works fine , but "api/search/pattern" is not working.

And we are sure there is no change in the client making this search request from quite a while.

Any pointers or insights or thoughts ?

-raj

Answer (score 0):

ok i think found the answer while troubleshooting :

We had two artifacts with this naming convention :

1. "iamartifact" and "iAmartifact" , only diff is that letter a is capital.
2. When we imported the system in the new box .. it basically created a folder "iamartifact" and put all the artfacts from "iamartifact" and "iAmartifact" under this folder.
3. now when we tried to do a query on "iAmartifact" it didnt worked using pattern api .. which is correct as that folder didnt exist.

So kind of learned two things :

1. artifactory merged the artifacts under these two hierarchies
2. seems like aql is case in sensitive at least in version 4.6.0